# TSQL Query Assistance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

What is the best way to achive this? I am not very good with joins and I think thats what It will have to be in this case. Just need some assistance on this.

I have 2 tables, an employee table and a records table. My query is going to grab a single row from table 1 and insert it into table 2. The question is, how can I do this and also pass variables?

I thought about doing this:

```
INSERT INTO table 2
(
 col1
,col2
)
SELECT 
  col1
 ,col2
FROM table 1
WHERE user = col1
```

But I also need to add variables that are not in the table but things I have passed to the stored procedure.

I think it will have to be a join but not sure how to join and insert with the data I got back.

```
Table 1
-Col 1
-Col 2
-Col 3
-Col 4
-Col 5


Table 2
-Col 1
-Col 2
-Col 3
-Col 4
```

Comment: Please mention some schema details, and also if there are any common columns in the 2 tables for which value need to be matched.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply *use* the variables. You may be over-thinking it.

```
INSERT INTO table 2
(
 col1
,col2
,col3
)
SELECT 
 col1
 ,col2
 ,@MyVariable
FROM table 1
WHERE user = col1
```

**EDIT**: Removed variable declaration, as the OP noted that the variable is a stored proc parameter (thanks for pointing this out, @Sonam).

Comment: I was under the impression that anything in the select query had to come from that table. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: @Ryan Henderson: She doesn't have to declare the variable as she is getting it from the stored procedure which is passed as a parameter.